# ClientSideEvents on ASP:Net repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm creating a textbox control in a repeater. Here is .cs code:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    Est estimationItem = (Est)e.Item.DataItem;
    TextBox txtWeekly = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtWeekly");
    txtWeekly.Text = estimationItem.SMEst.ToString();   
}
```

And here is .aspx code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="WeeklyEst" OnItemDataBound="WeeklyEst_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
           <tr>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtWeekly" runat="server">  
                 <ClientSideEvents OnTextChanged="function(s, e) { alert('AlertIsHere!');}" />
              </asp:TextBox>
         </td>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
             <td>
             </td>
          </tr> 
        </table>
     </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to do is firing an alert when text changed on text box. How can I do this? CliendSideEvent fire on another textbox but in repeater control, it doesn't work.

Comment: My mistake. ClientSideEvents are usable only DevExpress controls, not on standard ASP.Net controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ItemDataBound event of Repeater control, you can do this like..., if i understood you correctly

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            TextBox mytxt = e.Item.FindControl("txtWeekly") as TextBox;
            // you can just pass "this" instead of "mytxt.ClientID" and get the ID from the DOM element
            mytxt.Attributes.Add("onchange", "doStuff('" + mytxt.ClientID + "');");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Talha, I did it using ..Attributes.Add()... and myText.ClientSideEvents.TextChanged

Comment: Not exactly; but it was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you donot want to do this in codebehind then you can use jquery ,it would be lot easier

$('.txtbox').change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});

just give cssclass 'txtbox' to your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

What about this **unobtrusive approach**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // select all input text ending with txtWeekly as repeater control
            // will create something like rptWeeklyEst$ctl00$txtWeekly
            $('input[name$="txtWeekly"][type=text]').change(function () {
                alert('textbox changed to ' + $(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptWeeklyEst" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtWeekly" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <br />
        Nope
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNope" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```